# How to check if string of numbers contain serial numbers or all same numbers?

Tags: ios, regex, validation, uitextfield, nsstring

In my iOS project, there is a `textfield` for mobile number (required filed) and field employees enter placeholder numbers. Before that, basic validations are already done as below:

> Here are the validations already done:

- Only numbers are allowed run time.
- Phone number will at-least 10 digits and not more than that which is checked at submit time.

> Here are the things which I need to validate:

- Check if string of textfield contains serial numbers  or all same
- Check if string of textfield contains all same numbers

If logically, serial number logic is not possible, I can go
   with only same number restriction.

Is there any REGEX to check what I need?

**NOTE: App is used in India only and never outside India.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple and flawless workaround for it. As I know that this field will have exactly 10 numbers, I just filtered few pre-defines numbers:

```
+(BOOL)stringIsSerialMobileNumber:(NSString *)text
{
    NSArray *array = @[@"0000000000", 
                       @"1111111111",
                       @"2222222222", 
                       @"3333333333", 
                       @"4444444444", 
                       @"5555555555",
                       @"6666666666", 
                       @"7777777777",
                       @"8888888888", 
                       @"9999999999",
                       @"1234567890",
                       @"0123456789"];

    return [array containsObject:text];
}
```

Comment: This is not an apt solution. For Indian numbers, 999999999 and 888888888 are valid number. Try using libPhoneNumber library to validate the number instead.

https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS